# msysgit and non-ascii characters in home directory

Tags: git, msysgit

I have installing msysgit. When launching Git bash I get the following error, which seems to be related to the non-ascii `å` in the username:

[image]

Creating a new user account with ascii-safe characters solves the problem, but is it possible to solve this and use my current account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a folder called `home` under C:\
2. Open CMD (not git bash) and type in:
   [image]
   This will create a symbolic link from C:\home\hakon to C:\Users\Håkon
3. Go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\etc`
4. Right-click on the file called `profile` and choose properties. Give yourself full access to this file on the security tab.
5. Open `profile` in a text-editor and find the comment `# Set up USER's home directory`. Update `HOME` with the new symbolic path:

[image]

Save `profile` and re-launch Git Bash, and you should be ready to go

Comment: Note that the 'mklink' command doesn't work on XP but should work on Vista and later.